# According to the Catholic Church is the ordering of the events in the Gospels (prior to the Passion) important to understanding salvation?

Tags: catholicism, life-of-jesus, gospels, chronology

I really love The Chosen, but I noticed that the chronology of some of the events, when certain parables were told, etc.  Teaching the Lords Prayer to children prior to public ministry, these are all very interesting ideas and a wonderful take on Jesus' mission.

For instance, I had to go and look up when the Parable of the Net was told (Matthew 13), that's certainly after Peter and Andrew started following him,  I'm not poking holes in The Chosen, I'm just wondering if the Catholic Church or prominent theologians who would be acceptable to the Catholic faith, would consider the ordering of the events in the public ministry of Jesus to be of import to salvation?

Comment: I could possibly get an answer. But I would like to know what you define as prior to the Passion! Last couple of months or some other space of time, such as weeks or hours?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creation order of events: Was there unanimous consent among the Church Fathers?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/32578/creation-order-of-events-was-there-unanimous-consent-among-the-church-fathers)

Comment: @geremia, I'm guessing you didn't want to hammer-close as dupe, but that question is A) A Church Fathers answer, not necessarily present Catholic Consensus and B) About Genesis, not the Gospels

Comment: @PeterTurner Yes, I'm not sure why some questions "hammer-close" and others only add a "Does this answer your question?" comment. I'm guessing it has to do with how the question is tagged.

Comment: This is not an official Catholic answer, but... I can't imagine *why* it would be important. I would not expect even knowing a particular parable would be important. Such things can *teach* us, certainly, but are hardly "core doctrine". Heck, we've been debating recently whether *belief in the Trinity* is mandatory. Note that https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/81084 might have an answer for you...